# sklearn - cross validation with precision scoring for a subset of classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, scikit-learn

I have a dataset for classification with 3 class labels `[0,1,2]`.

I want to run cross validation and try several estimators, but I am interested in scoring with precision of only classes 1 and 2. I don't care about the precision of class 0, and I don't want its scoring to throw off the CV optimization. I also don't care about the recall of any of the classes. In other words, I want to make sure that whenever 1 or 2 are predicted, it's with very high confidence.

So the question is, how do I run `cross_val_score` and tell its scoring function to disregard precision of class 0?

**UPDATE**: Here's an example answer code, according to the accepted answer:

```
def custom_precision_score(y_true,y_pred):
  precision_tuple, recall_tuple, fscore_tuple, support_tuple = metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred)
  precision_tuple = precision_tuple[1:]
  support_tuple = support_tuple[1:]
  weighted_precision = np.average(precision_tuple, weights=support_tuple)
  return weighted_precision

custom_scorer = metrics.make_scorer(custom_precision_score)

scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, featuresArray, targetArray, cv=10, scoring=custom_scorer)
```

Comment: `cross_val_score` takes a scorer callable object, to define your scoring see [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#defining-your-scoring-strategy-from-score-functions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cross_val_score` includes a [scorer callable object](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html) that can be [set with your own test strategy](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) using `make_scorer`. And you can set your the groups that you are going to test in self-defined score function `score_func(y, y_pred, **kwargs)`, which is called by `make_scorer`.

Comment: great, I updated the question with example answer code. I thought there would be a shorter way, for example something that `precision_score` itself implements, but this works as well :)